# How to Return a String from a List of Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a program for the following:

*Given a list of users, write a function, names_and_roles that returns all of user's names and roles in a string with each value labeled.*

I didn't meet the question requirements for the program. I'm guessing it's because I returned a list of dictionaries instead. How could I return a string such that my output looks the same?

```
users = [
{
     'name': 'Homer', 
     'role': 'Clerk', 
     'dob': '12/02/1988',
     'admin': False 
}, 
{
     'name': 'Lisa', 
     'role': 'Staff', 
     'dob': '01/30/1965',
     'admin': False 
}, 
{
     'name': 'Marge', 
     'role': 'Associate', 
     'dob': '09/10/1980',
     'admin': True 
}
]

def names_and_roles(some_users):
      employees = {some_user['name']:some_user['role'] for some_user in users}
return employees

employee_list = (names_and_roles(users))

for user, role in employee_list.items():
  print("Name:", user)
  print("Role:", role)
  print("\n")
```

Comment: Start by fixing your indentation.

Comment: „I didn't meet the question requirements for the program.“ What *is* the question requirement? What exactly does „a string with each value labeled“ mean? Strings are individual values that don’t have labels.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. You should probably try something before posting your question, but here is on way for example:

```
["Name: {}, Role: {}".format(u['name'], u['role']) for u in users]
```

Or if it needs to be one big string:

```
sep = "\n"
sep.join("Name: {}, Role: {}".format(u['name'], u['role']) for u in users)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I absolutely didn't mean to be rude to you. Reading your question I thought you had tried other things to build a string or a list of strings but didn't manage to do it so I meant to be useful for your next questions: it is always better to provide things you tried. You are totally right, I should have asked for clarification instead of wording my answer that way, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the code that prints out what is in `employee_list` and move it into `names_and_roles`, but adding each line to a string instead of printing it.

Then you should see that it would actually be easier to do that with the original list of users, and avoid making the dictionary.